# Is the war of Gog and Magog a spiritual war?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, messiah

I read somewhere that, *"That the war of Gog and Magog will be an internal, spiritual war, when everyone will have to battle to remain strong with his emunah, but it will not be a war fought with guns and weapons."*

Is there any *sefer* that says this?

Comment: Yes. Wherever you read it.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? @msh210 I assume the OP meant either that he forgot the source, or that his source is not authoritative enough.

Comment: @Ypnypn, my downvote was because the question doesn't include all the info that one can reasonably expect an asker to include and which would help people answer the question. Specifically, the following are four very different questions, and I don't know which the asker means. 1. I read on a Christian Web site that.... 2. I read in _A Summary of Tannaic Eschatology_ that.... 3. I read in Fax-Homily that.... 4. I read the _Imre Emes_ cited as saying that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is something based upon Chovot haLevavot, in Shaar Yichud haMaaseh §5, where Bahya ibn Paquda describes the "real" battle in one's life as being against an internal enemy, rather than against external forces ([link](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38062&pgnum=186)). This story is also related by R' Yishaya Horowitz (Shnei Luchot haBrit II: Parshat Korach), and so the version you heard may also be based upon a commentary to that text. You can read his version [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9737&pgnum=140), about eight lines up from the bottom of the left-hand column.